# In datatables, how can we show headers while loading, and then when data loads, show all the datatable?

Tags: python, html, django, datatable

I am running a Django project in which I have a html page to render where I am displaying some data in tabular format using datatables.

I am getting that data for the table from API, so it takes time of about 1 or 2 seconds.

During this loading time I am using a spinner.

But I want the table headers and the filters and search tab that comes with datatables to be displayed while those 2 seconds of loading time, and when the data is ready, complete datatable will be displayed.

How can I do that?

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code, so I am making a complete guess here: Maybe you just need to use the [processing](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing) option. But since there are no details, I do not know if that will actually help, or not.

Comment: You can take the [tour] and also read [ask] for guidance on how to write a better question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.